# Aeson's deriveJSON doesn't work as expected for enums

Tags: haskell, aeson

I usually write my own `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` instances, but I decided to use `deriveJSON` for a type because it was so simple:

```
data Priority = HIGH | MEDIUM | LOW deriving Show
$(deriveToJSON id ''Priority)

main = BS.putStrLn . encode $ HIGH
```

I would've expected the `JSON` derivation to just write out the enum as a string. Instead, it's the key to a hash! `{"HIGH":[]}`

Why is this the default behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `aeson` doesn't distinguish between sum types like your `Priority` and more sophisticated types like `data PriorityAndDetails = HIGH { highReason :: Text, alertType :: Alert } | MEDIUM { personResponsible :: Person } | LOW`. Fundamentally each of these types are "just a data constructor with *n* arguments".

In `Priority` `HIGH`, `MED`, and `LOW` are each just data constructors with zero arguments. In `PriorityAndDetails` `HIGH`, `MED`, and `LOW` are each just data constructors with some number of named arguments, 2, 1, and 0 respectively.

Generally I've found that you're likely to need to create your own `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` instances for anything besides early prototyping.